# WordPress Sub Directory install, urls with child or category not resolving

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks, subdirectory

I've got an install inside it's own sub-directory following the standard process to have it as the live site (copying index.php & .htaccess to the root) & this works fine for standard pages but I have an issue with URLs containing things like a parent page name or post category in them not resolving and giving a 404.

**Example:**

"www.domain.com.au/subdir/about" -

With the site address etc set correctly, WordPress removes the "subdir" step & sends you to the correct page with the URL

Loads correctly to - "www.domain.com.au/about"

But URL's that contain anything else like a parent page name or a category will not remove the "subdir" & load a 404, So

"www.domain.com.au/subdir/blog/post-name" - Goes to 404

& "www.domain.com.au/subdir/parent-page/child-page" - Goes to 404.

I've read all I can to try and adjust it but no version of a .htaccess re direct seems to be able to fix it.

Is there a way to let WordPress know to remove "subdir" for these URLs?

Happy to provide for info, so just let me know

Comment: Did you save your permalinks after moving the files?

Comment: I believe I did, I've always followed the "giving Wordpress it's own directory" information on the Wordpress site. I think that to solve/avoid this issue I'll begin using sub domains instead of sub directories. So I can avoid urls like - www.domain.com.au/subdir/blog/post-name where the "subdir" causes issues, that will then be in front as "subdir.domain.com.au/blog/post-name" & should be easier to replace the url overall.

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess

### RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/my_subdir/ RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my_subdir/$1 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ RewriteRule ^(/)?$ my_subdir/index.php [L]

or
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeMHe.png)

Comment: Thanks methababu, Would you mind explaining what this is doing. Is it making sure the site knows it new url?

Comment: however sometimes beginners end up installing WordPress in a subdirectory instead of the root directory of their website, e.g. http://www.example.com/wordpress/ instead of http://www.example.com. If you accidentally installed WordPress in a subdirectory and now want to move it to the root directory, then you’re in the right place. In this article, we will show you how to get rid of /wordpress/ from your site’s URL

Comment: Hi methababu, I installed the site in a sub directory on purpose & have adjusted the site address & index.php to accomodate this (as per WP documentation) but it is only some urls which do not resolve correctly.

Links that contain the sub directory & also a category name or are a child page, don't remove the sub directory automatically.

So, www.domain.com/subdir/about - works fine & loads as www.domain.com/about

But, www.domain.com/subdir/blog/post - gives a 404 as it won't remove the "subdir/" section of the url.